# list all users in active directory using c++

Tags: c++, active-directory, adsi, domaincontroller

I am working on active directory and I am new to this.Here I need to list all the users in the active directory using c++ and ADSI.It might be duplicate post,but i went through many posts and I got an idea to use ADSI.So give some idea to proceed further.

Comment: Refer sample code here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676882%28v=vs.85%29.aspx, C++ code example searches the current domain for all users, or a specific user based on a specified filter.

Comment: I visited this link,but i didn't get a clear idea to list all users in the domain..

Comment: what exactly you don't understand from the code? It is fairly straight-forward.

Comment: You're kidding, right? The code is horrific.